# How to fix "TypeError: f() takes 3 positional arguments when 4 were given error" when fitting a curve

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to find the x-offset gaussian function that, when convolved (with numpy.convolve) with one set of data, fits to another. When I try to fit this complex series of operations against my data however, it gives me an error regarding the number of arguments.

I have 5 signals with their magnitudes recorded at slightly different dates. In theory, the later 4 signals (g, r, i, and z) can be modelled as being equal to the first signal u after having been convolved with some convolution function that I have modelled as a gaussian curve.

I am trying to find the parameters a mu and sigma that describes the gaussian for each of the 4 signal convolutions. I am doing this by interpolating the first signal u to generate more points describing it, putting those interpolated values through the convolution with the unknown gaussian, then using the scipy curve_fit function to find the parameters that best fits each of the 4 recorded signals.

I have tried nesting my functions in various ways, I have tried putting all the functions into a single command rather than calling to functions i define myself, this is the closest i have gotten to successfully performing this task.

```
#defined the gaussian function with the 3 parameters a mu and sig to be found. 
#test_x is a numpy.linspace array with numbers from -10 to 10.
def gauss(a, mu, sig):
    return a * np.exp(-np.power(test_x - mu, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sig, 2.)))

#defined the convolution of the callable interpolated u data (interpu) with 
#the defined gaussian function gauss
def gaussconv(a, mu, sig):
    return np.convolve(interpu, gauss(a, mu, sig))

#defined a function that should in theory model the convolved interpolation 
#and gaussian against the inputted x data datex and magnitude dana normx, with 
#the initial guesses for a mu and sig being 0.15, 1, and 0.5 respectively
def fit(datex, normx):
    return spo.curve_fit(gaussconv, datex, normx, p0=[0.15,1,0.5])
```

Ideally it should output with the calculated a mu and sig values that best fit the convolution against the recorded data, but i get this error message instead:

```
TypeError: gaussconv() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [edit] and add the full error message

Comment: add fourth argument in `def gaussconv(a, mu, sig, arg4):` and display all arguments to see what you get. Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

curve_fit() is passing the data AND the three parameters (4 total items) to gaussconv(). The first parameter for gaussconv() should be the data.